# Thread creation on a derived class method results in error

Tags: c++, boost, abstract-class, virtual-functions

I have an abstract class as follows:

```
    class AbstractClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<AbstractClass> {
    public:
        virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;

        virtual bool Start() = 0; 
        virtual void Stop() = 0;
    };
```

This is the derived class:

```
    class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass {
    public:
        bool Start() override;
        void Stop() override;
    }
```

I am trying to create an object of derived class and a thread for the derived class method in another file:

```
    // Create object
    derivedClass_.reset(...);

    //Start a thread for the derived class method
    std::unique_ptr<boost::thread> derivedClassThread_;

    derivedClassThread_.reset(new boost::thread(std::bind(&DerivedClass::Start, 
    derivedClass_)));
```

When I compile this, I get some weird errors:

> error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<bool
> (DerivedClass::* const&(const volatile
> std::shared_ptr&))()>'

Could someone help me out?

Comment: Hard to tell for sure if that'll fix it for you, but this would certainly make a lot more sense: `derivedClassThread_ = std::make_shared<boost::thread>([derived_class_]{ derived_class_->Start(); });`

Comment: Hi @Frank, Thanks for the reply. 

Here is what I got when I compiled:
error: capture of non-variable 'derived_class_'
    derivedClassThread_ = std::make_shared<boost::thread>([derived_class_]{ derived_class_->Start(); });
                                                           

error: 'this' was not captured for this lambda function
    dderivedClassThread_ = std::make_shared<boost::thread>([derived_class_]{ derived_class_->Start(); });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not selfcontained, so we have to guess things. Here's what I think you would have/want:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8df3be991552428b)**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

class AbstractClass : public std::enable_shared_from_this<AbstractClass> {
  public:
    virtual ~AbstractClass() = default;

    virtual bool Start() = 0;
    virtual void Stop()  = 0;
};

class DerivedClass : public AbstractClass {
  public:
    bool Start() override {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
    void Stop() override { }
};

int main()
{
    // Create object
    std::shared_ptr<AbstractClass> derivedClass_ =
        std::make_shared<DerivedClass>();

    // Start a thread for the derived class method
    auto derivedClassThread_ = std::make_unique<boost::thread>(
        [derivedClass_] { derivedClass_->Start(); });

    if (derivedClassThread_ && derivedClassThread_->joinable())
        derivedClassThread_->join();

    derivedClassThread_ = std::make_unique<boost::thread>(
        std::bind(&AbstractClass::Start, derivedClass_));

    if (derivedClassThread_ && derivedClassThread_->joinable())
        derivedClassThread_->join();
}
```

Which compiles without trouble.

> **Updated** in response to the comment, showed that you can actually do it with `std::bind` just the same.

Prints:

```
virtual bool DerivedClass::Start()
virtual bool DerivedClass::Start()
```

Comment: "Using `std::bind` would require taking the address of any concrete method override" -- would it? IIRC member function pointers can perform virtual dispatching when called.

Comment: @Quentin You can try. How would you indicate which semantics you desire? `&AbstractClass::Start` looks odd (because it's pure virtual), and it would also be odd when `&DerivedClass::Start` would **not** return a de-virtualized `void(DerivedClass::*)()` - if not, how would the language support getting that pointer?

Comment: @Quentin I stand corrected! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1fa2ef9ba476f10 It turns out that `&DerivedClass::Start` does NOT devirtualize as I had expected. (Leaves my previous question comment hanging, but  fixed the answer)